# Using an event wait handle to block for window closed, then wrapping as async-await. Acceptable?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-store-apps, task-parallel-library, event-wait-handle

I have a window displaying service, with a CloseWindow method that is called by the view. I want to create a blocking method in my calling code. So I can block while a window pops up and to allow outputs to come back from the window.

Is this use of Manual Reset acceptable? Are there any technical or design problems with it or with the way I mix it with TPL?

Here is that service

```
private readonly ManualResetEvent closedEvent = new ManualResetEvent(true);

public void DisplayWindow(){
     window = new MyWindow();
} 

public void CloseWindow() {
     window.Close();
     closedEvent.Set();
}

//new
public async Task WaitClosed()
    {
        await Task.Run(() => this.closedEvent.WaitOne());
    }
```

here is some code that calls it.

```
public void DisplayWindow(string content, string title)
    {
        dialogservice.DisplayWindow();
    }

    public async Task DisplayWindowAsync(string content, string title)
    {
        dialogservice.DisplayWindow();
        await dialogservice.WaitClosed();
    }
```

Comment: Why not `ShowDialog`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it could be done more simply and without the hung thread:

```
private readonly TaskCompletionSource<bool> windowClosed
    = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

public Task WindowClosed { get { return windowClosed.Task; } }


public void CloseWindow() {
    window.Close();
    windowClosed.TrySetResult(true);
}
```

with:

```
await dialogservice.WindowClosed;
```

Comment: Thanks. Just to be safe, I set it to true in the constructor, and I make it false in  the DisplayWindow(). And this comes with a way of passing my TResult back, excellent.

Comment: @NathanCooper no; do **NOT** set it true in the constructor; the `true`/`false` means nothing here; if you set a result, **you are telling it that it is complete**. You don't want that. You want it to be incomplete.